# Django HTML Dropdown

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to make a html dropdown and pass the values into Postgrase SQL database. My dropdown values are being retrieved from another database table. It gives me a MultiValueKeyDictError every time I submit the form. I know I can use forms.py to do the same thing but I want to explore the HTML way of doing this.

My HTML file

```
                            <form action = "" method = "post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <label for = "LogType"></label>
                            <input id ="LogType" type = "text" value = "{{ user.department }}">
                            <label for ="DelayCategory">Delay Category</label>
                            <select id = "delaycategory" class = "form-control">
                            {%if  user.department == 'TechAssembly'%}
                                {%for techdelay in techdelay%}
                                    <option value = "{{ techdelay.DelayCode }}">{{ techdelay.DelayCategory}}</option>
                                {%endfor%}
                            {%endif%}
                            {%if  user.department == 'Testing'%}
                                {%for testdelay in testdelay%}
                                    <option value = "{{ testdelay.DelayCode }}">{{ testdelay.DelayCategory}}</option>
                                {%endfor%}
                            {%endif%}
                            </select>
                            <label for =  "iterations">Iterations</label>
                            <input type = "number" id = "iterations">
                        
                        <center><input type="submit" value=Submit id = "button"></center>
                        </form>
```

My Views.py file

```
def rulesView(request, user_name):
testdelay = TestingDelayCategory.objects.all()
techdelay = TechDelayCategory.objects.all()
if request.method == "POST":
    rulesnew = rules()
    rulesnew.DelayCategory = request.GET['DelayCategory']
    rulesnew.LogType = request.POST('LogType')
    rulesnew.iterations = request.POST('iterations')
    rulesnew.save()
context = {
    'techdelay':techdelay,
    'testdelay':testdelay,
}
return render(request, 'rules/rules.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rulesnew.DelayCategory = request.GET['DelayCategory']
rulesnew.LogType = request.POST('LogType')
rulesnew.iterations = request.POST('iterations')
```

Have a second look at this: `request.GET` should be `request.POST`  and `request.POST('LogType')` should be `request.POST['LogType']` same with iterations.

The error message should include the exact line where the errors was raised. So it would have been way easier to debug if you have told us that the error was raised e.g. in this line `rulesnew.LogType = request.POST('LogType')`